# Specifying multiple files with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, x86

I know how to override one library with LD_PRELOAD, for example, as follows.

```
LD_PRELOAD=./getpid.so ./testpid
```

Now my question is how to override multiple files. Say I want to override both getpid and getid, how would I specify that?

Answer (score 93):

According to the `ld.so` [manpage](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), it is a space separated list.  So:

```
LD_PRELOAD="path1 path2"
```

ought to work.

Comment: According to the man-page colons are also accepted, e.g.:

`LD_PRELOAD=path1:path2`

Comment: Interesting.  In the section on LD_LIBRARY_PATH,  the page  mentions that semi-colons and colons are valid, but makes no mention of spaces.  The parsing of $ORIGIN, $LIB, and $PLATFORM are (I believe) new.  Spaces were always a bit surprising, and I find it odd that they are valid in LD_PRELOAD but not LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Note that the page dated 2001 (from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/Archive/man-pages-2.00.tar.bz2) states: " LD_PRELOAD: A  whitespace-separated  list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared libraries to be loaded before all others."  I cannot find a change in binutils, and would be curious to know if this is merely an omission in the documentation or if the behavior has changed recently.

Comment: Since it is spaces, if libraries to preload have a space in their pathname it will break, right?

Comment: @MetallicPriest, I think this solution solves this question, can you check and maybe mark it as the solution?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, the [manpage linked in the answer](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) states "*separated by spaces or colons*". To complete your answer, I suggest to add also the option with spaces.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to have the overridden version of both `getpid` and `getid` in a single `.so` which you give to `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: hmm, interesting! Will try that!

Comment: its nice to make a single library that holds all the functions you want, a bit more simple to do. this answer is nicest, though others are more correct.