# Effects of replacing stripped libraries with unstripped libraries in /usr/lib and /lib path in linux for running valgrind

Tags: c, linux, debugging, shared-libraries, valgrind

I have below libs in **/usr/lib** path(stripped) which needs to be replaced with unstripped types.

```
/usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.14.7
/usr/lib/liblog4c.so.3.3.0
/usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.40.0.0
/lib/ld-2.24.so
```

As I need to run **valgrind** for one of my process (say : **snmp agent** process), having libs with debug symbols will help in identifying file location, function name info.

From **/proc/$pid/maps** file found that in addition to snmp agent process, there are some other processes also using these listed libraries. So what will happen to these processes when I replace the existing stripped libs with unstripped libraries in the same path.

or

How to run valgrind without disturbing other processes which are using the libs of interest.

Comment: I'm not sure if dealing with `ld-*.so` may require special handling, but for the others, that sounds more like a job for `LD_PRELOAD`

Comment: @Frank - Any example available to use `LD_PRELOAD`. Does any crash occur to other processes upon replacing unstripped libs.

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/426260/4442671, and no, other processes still use the system's libraries and are unaffected.

Comment: @Frank- So I have to place the unstripped libs in a different path and refer it in LD_PRELOAD env variable. Also I have multiple libs, so for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474363/specifying-multiple-files-with-ld-preload) will be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what operating system are you using?

Normally the way that you should do this is to install the debuginfo packages. Most Linux distributions split out the debuginfo, so that you can install stripped binaries but also optionally install the separate debuginfo. Tools like gdb and Valgrind know where to look for the debuginfo files and will read them when needed.

If you do that then you should not need to install un-stripped binaries.