# Is it possible to define a symbol dynamically such that it will be found by dlsym?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, gnu, dlsym, dladdr

I want to simulate loading symbols from a shared library for testing purposes.
Is there a way to define a symbol at runtime programmatically such that `dlsym` will find it?

For example:

```
 dl_define_symbol("foobar")
 ....    
 void* f = dlsym("foobar",RTLD_NEXT);
```

The question is does anything (dl, ld, elfutils?) expose API functions that would make this possible?

Such functionality probably exists inside `ld` but it is possibly not exposed.

Put another way is there a symmetric API for `dlsym()` et al?

---

For context, I am writing automated tests for the behaviour of an application involving library interposition using LD_PRELOAD and `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT)`.
This is actually a malloc interposer along the lines of the linked questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17850402/1569204
- [How to correctly interpose malloc allowing for LD_PRELOAD chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71882426/1569204)

I want to test the case where different symbols come from different libraries.
This can be detected by using `dladdr` on the symbols.
Pseudo-code:

```
void* f1 = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc");
void* f2 = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"malloc_usable_size");
// handle failures...
Dl_info info1;
dladdr(f1,&info1);
Dl_info info2;
dladdr(f2,&info2);
// handle failures...
if (info1.dli_fbase != info2.dli_fbase)
{
    // malloc_usable_size() is provided by a different library than malloc()
    // so we probably shouldn't use it
    f2 = nullptr; 
    // set flags accordingly
}
```

An example of this in practice is electric-fence.
If I chain:

LD_PRELOAD="mymalloc.so electric-fence.so"

You find that `malloc_usable_size()` comes from `libc` while `malloc` comes from `electric-fence`.
Granted electric-fence is not so common any more.

This is of course possible by using a real shared library in the tests. This question asks if there is a shortcut.
Another approach would to try and interpose dlsym() itself. This is somewhat scary. Though see - [How can I intercept dlsym calls using LD_PRELOAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599026/how-can-i-intercept-dlsym-calls-using-ld-preload)